# Uniqueness theorem for analytic function defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, linear-pde

It is well known that if the zeroes of an analytic (holomorphic) function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ must be isolated unless the function is identically zero, where $\Omega$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$. Consequently, if $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a domain $D$ containing $\alpha$ and $\exists$ a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $D$ such that $z_n \to \alpha$ as $n \to \infty$, $z_n \neq \alpha$ and $f(z_n)=g(z_n)$ for all $n$, then 
$f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in D.$

> Are there any same or similar result for multivariable analytic function $f: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$? Here $\Sigma$ is a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

For example, if $f,g: \Sigma \to \mathbb{R}$ are analytic functions satisfying $f(z)=g(z)$ for all $z \in \Sigma_1$ and for some open subset $\Sigma_1$ in $\Sigma$, then $f\equiv g$ on $\Sigma.$

Please let me know if you have any comment or reference for this question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [Sets of uniqueness in $\mathbb{C}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705476/sets-of-uniqueness-in-mathbbc2) AND [A sequence that tell us if a holomorphic function of several variables is identically zero](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109548/a-sequence-that-tell-us-if-a-holomorphic-function-of-several-variables-is-identi) AND [Uniqueness of analytic continuation on a domain of C^n](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61294/uniqueness-of-analytic-continuation-on-a-domain-of-cn)